# c: How can I print only the highest numbered vowel?

Tags: c

I just want to print highest numbered vowel.
For ex: `the cat is the cat.` In this sentence,

```
the vowel a is repeated 2 times  
the vowel e is repeated 2 times  
the vowel i is repeated 1 times  
the vowel o is repeated 0 times  
the vowel u is repeated 0 times
```

I just want to see `a` and `e` in the console.

Here is the code.

```
void vowel(char st2[]){

   char vow[]="aeiou"; //vowel
   int i=0,j=0,count=0;
   while(vow[i]!='\0'){ //loop until sentence ends
       count=0;
       for(j=0;j<strlen(st2);j++) 
       {
           if(st2[j]==vow[i]){ //increment the counter by one if one letter in the sentence is equal to the vowels
               count++;                   
           }
       }
      
       printf("the vowel %c is repeated %d times\n",vow[i],count);
       i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the current behaviour of the code? If something's wrong, what is it?

Comment: not wrong, code prints all vowels, just I want to change this

Comment: @MMZK1526 as clarified by an edit.

Comment: Why not keep an array of `counts`, one for each vowel, and do not print anything in the while loop. After having the count of each vowel in the `counts` array, print out only the index corresponding to the highest number.

Comment: Don't put `strlen` in your loop test.  It needlessly slows your code.  Since you're using C, performance must be an issue, so don't write code like this. Think about it.  If you were doing it by hand, would you count the length of the string each and every time?  Of course not.  So why is your code doing it?  It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, in this version, we count how many occurrences there are of a vowel, and only print the highest one.

```
void vowel(char st2[]){

   char vow[]="aeiou"; //vowel
   int length = strlen(st2);
   int counts[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
   int i=0,j=0,count=0;
   while(vow[i]!='\0'){ //loop until sentence ends
       count=0;
       for(j=0;j<length;j++) 
       {
           if(st2[j]==vow[i]){ //increment the counter by one if one letter in the sentence is equal to the vowels
               count++; 
               counts[i] = count;                  
           }
       }
       i++;
   }
   int highest = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(counts[i] > highest){
        highest = counts[i];
    }
   }
   for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++){
    if(counts[i] == highest){
        printf("the vowel %c is repeated %d times\n",vow[i],highest);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The elegance of C is that one can obtain functionality with very little code.

```
int main() {
    char *str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    char which = 'a'; // default
    int maxCnt = 0;

    for( char *pv = "aeiou"; *pv; pv++ ) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for( char *cp = str; *cp; cp++ )
            cnt += ( *cp == *pv );

        if( cnt > maxCnt ) {
            maxCnt = cnt;
            which = *pv;
        }
    }
    if( maxCnt )
        printf( "Vowel '%c' occurs %d times.\n", which, maxCnt );
    else
        printf( "NO vowels found in '%s'.\n", str );

    return 0;
}
```